# How to Display SAS results in a table

Tags: sas, multiple-results

I am very new to SAS. I am performing many tests at once using the BY statement (e.g. analyzing by Sex and by Strain to get separate results for each Sex x Strain combination). Results are usually generated as many separate tables. How can I generate a table of results which have all of a single estimate (e.g. p-values of fixed effects tests) for each combination of levels in the BY columns (e.g. for each Sex x Strain combination)?

Results format wanted:

```
Sex Strain  p-value
-------------------
F   Exp     0.115
F   Ctrl    0.57
M   Exp     0.024
M   Ctrl    0.483
```

My current code is:

```
proc mixed data=dataset;
class Strain EXPERIMENT EXPERIMENTAL_STRAIN EXPERIMENTAL_SEX;
model Response = Strain / ddfm=satterth;
random EXPERIMENT;
BY EXPERIMENTAL_STRAIN EXPERIMENTAL_SEX;
run;
```

In JMP this could be accomplished by right-clicking on a particular table in the Results Report (e.g. the table of Fixed Effects Tests) and selecting "Make Combined Data Table". If SAS results could be exported into JMP, this could be a solution.

Comment: It really depends on what procedure you are using to produce the report. Most will have OUT= options to let you it tell it what dataset name to use to store the results. No need to try to copy the report output into a dataset, just tell it to make the dataset in your code.

Comment: Post your current code so we can at least offer options. Right now we'd have to guess as to what you're doing...

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/01/09/ods-output-any-statistic.html